# List dates between two date range

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, while-loop

I have table 1 with 3 columns id, startdate and enddate. With order id being the primary key how do I list the dates between the date range Startdate and Enddate?

What I have:

```
id     Startdate     EndDate
1      2/11/2014     2/13/2014
2      2/15/2014     2/17/2014
```

What I need:

```
id       Date
1      2/11/2014
1      2/12/2014
1      2/13/2014
2      2/15/2014
2      2/16/2014
2      2/17/2014
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Does the enumeration of the dates need to be inside SQL Server or is it only used in a separate business logic layer? If the former, then an auxiliary table of dates could help.

Comment: This is completely internal within the SQL layer. I was thinking a while looping would work but not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use recursive CTE:

```
WITH tmp AS (
    SELECT  id, StartDate AS [Date], EndDate
    FROM    MyTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  tmp.id, DATEADD(DAY,1,tmp.[Date]), tmp.EndDate
    FROM    tmp
    WHERE   tmp.[Date] < tmp.EndDate
)

SELECT tmp.ID, tmp.[Date]
FROM tmp
ORDER BY tmp.id, tmp.[Date]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) -- For long intervals
```

If you have to use cursor/loop, most times you are doing it wrong.

Comment: This works like a charm. Thank you so much. I have one issue though. The enddate lists one day extra. For example while I need date range between 2/11/2014 2/13/2014, the above query displays dates till 2/14/2014. Could you guess where this query needs some fine tune?

Comment: Play around with the WHERE clause: `WHERE tmp.[Date] < tmp.EndDate`. This controls when the recursive CTE stops.

Comment: Thank you so much. This works now, I will figure out the date variation. I appreciate your assistance

Answer (score 0):

If you do a one-off setup of an auxiliary calendar table as shown at [Why should I consider using an auxiliary calendar table?](http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html), possibly omitting a lot of the columns if you don't need them, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Calendar  
(  
    dt SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,  

    Y SMALLINT,  
    M TINYINT,  
    D TINYINT
 ) 
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON 
DECLARE @dt SMALLDATETIME 
SET @dt = '20000101' 
WHILE @dt < '20300101' 
BEGIN 
    INSERT dbo.Calendar(dt) SELECT @dt 
    SET @dt = @dt + 1 
END;

UPDATE dbo.Calendar SET 
    Y = YEAR(dt),  
    M = MONTH(dt),  
    D = DAY(dt);
```

(You may well not need the Y, M, D columns at all, but I left those in to show that more data can be stored for fast access - the article I linked to shows how that could be used.)

Then if your table is named "so", your code would simply be

```
SELECT A.id, C.dt
FROM so AS A
JOIN Calendar AS C
ON C.dt >= A.StartDate AND C.dt<= A.EndDate
```

An advantage of using an auxiliary table like that is that your queries can be faster: the work done in setting one up is a one-time cost which doesn't happen during usage..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using CTE (to over come recursive and performance when date range is large) below query can be used to get the list of dates between two date range.

> DECLARE @StartDateSTR AS VARCHAR(32); DECLARE @EndDateSTR AS
>   VARCHAR(32); DECLARE @EndDate AS DATE; DECLARE @StartDate AS DATE;
>
> SET @StartDateSTR = '01/01/1990';  SET @EndDateSTR = '03/31/2025'; SET
>   @StartDate = CAST(@StartDateSTR AS date); SET @EndDate =
>   cast(@EndDateSTR AS date); SELECT
>       DATEADD(DAY, n1.rn - 1, @StartDate) AS dt FROM                        (SELECT rn=Row_number() OVER( ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM   sys.objects a 
>   CROSS JOIN sys.objects b CROSS JOIN sys.objects c CROSS JOIN
>   sys.objects d) as n1 WHERE  n1.[rn] <= Datediff(dd, @StartDate,
>   @EndDate)+1;